# Moving a line of code somehow alters the value of a register my x86-64 GNU assembler program

Tags: linux, 64-bit, att, gnu-assembler

Environment and tools:

- Ubuntu Linux
- GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
- GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34

Problem:
Moving a line of code in the source of an assembly program somehow changes the value of a register making the output of the program incorrect

Expected Output:
The program will return the factorial of 5 (120) as an exit code

Actual Output:
Exit code is 16

Code snippet of the problem:

```
// n! = n * (n - 1)!
dec %rax          # decrement the value of %rax by 1
push %rax         # then call factorial with it
call factorial    # the value returned by the function will be stored in %rax

mov 16(%rbp), %rbx  # copy the input to %rbx, this is the offending line

imul %rbx, %rax     # multiply the input to the result of factorial of (input - 1)
```

The code above works fine, but once I move `mov 16(%rbp), %rbx`, anywhere before `call factorial`, the result somehow changes.

Below is the full code if you are interested:

```
# PURPOSE: Get the factorial of a given number
# INPUT: Hardcoded values (non-negative and non-zero)
# OUTPUT: The value will be return as the program's exit code (0-255 only)
#         Use `echo $?` to get the exit code on a linux machine
.section    .data

.section    .rodata
input:      .8byte 5

.section    .text
.globl      _start

_start:
# push the parameters in reverse order and call the function
push input        # push input as the first argument
call factorial    # assign the address of the function to %rip (instruction pointer)
                  # and pushes the return address of the called function

add $8, %rsp      # clean the stack

# exit the program
mov %rax, %rdi    # set the return of the function as the exit code
mov $60, %rax     # set 60 (exit) as the system call number to %rax
syscall           # switch to kernel mode

/*
 * Computes the factorial of a number through recursion
 *
 * Parameters:
 *    param1 - the number to get the factorial of
 *
 * Return: the result of the factorial (stored in %rax)
 */
.type factorial, @function
factorial:
# create the stack frame
push %rbp       # push the current base pointer register
mov %rsp, %rbp  # assign the value of stack pointer register 
                # as the new value of the base pointer register
                # we will use the base pointer to access the return address,
                # local variables, and parameters

# copy the input to %rbx
mov 16(%rbp), %rax  # copy input to %rax


# if the input is less than or equals to 1 then we're done
cmp $1, %rax
jle return_factorial


// n! = n * (n - 1)!
dec %rax          # decrement the value of %rax by 1
push %rax         # then call factorial with it
call factorial    # the value returned by the function will be stored in %rax
mov 16(%rbp), %rbx  # copy the input to %rbx

imul %rbx, %rax     # multiply the input to the result of factorial of (input - 1)

return_factorial:
mov %rbp, %rsp      # reset the %rsp back to its original value before the call
pop %rbp            # reset the %rbp back to its original value before the call
ret                 # this is equivalent to doing pop %rip
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to deal with the stack in anyway in your factorial function. Also, if you move the line that's dealing with rbp above the call of the factorial, then you're dealing with an older value of what's on the stack, since factorial changes the stack.

Comment: That was it! I didn't realize that. Thanks!